# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

Error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
> Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, C:\Users\saura\AndroidStudioProjects\FutsalNepal\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@63c94fba) before task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

Here is my build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.androiddevs.mvvmnewsapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
}
```

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'

// Architectural Components
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"

// Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

// Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"

// Coroutines
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5'

// Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0"

// Navigation Components
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.1"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.1"

implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-rc02'

// Glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

}

Here is my settings.gradle:

```
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Futsal Nepal"
include ':app'
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, did you find a solution?